# Flutter: Camera disconnect exception when other camera apps are opened

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera2

I'm currently using the flutter `camera` package to record and save videos, but I've noticed that the camera preview runs into an exception when the device's camera is opened on another app or when face unlock is used on the lock screen.

I've tried using `didChangeAppLifecycleState` to possibly fetch or reinitialize the camera, but there's no success yet.

```
      await model.fetchCameras();
      if (model.cameras.isNotEmpty) {
        await model.onNewCameraSelected(model.cameras[model.cameraIndex], true);

      }
    }
```

This issue is currently opened [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18138) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23039#issuecomment-430221188), but haven't been resolved.

I get this exception when the device's camera is opened in another app. I tried disposing the camera and reinitializing it in the sample code above, but it doesn't work.

```
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468): android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): cancelRequest:458: Camera device no longer alive
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:814)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:95)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1134)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:526)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:737)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:242)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468): Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:458: Camera device no longer alive (code 4)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1980)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:402)
E/CameraCaptureSession(31468):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRe
```

Any Ideas, on how to force the camera package to reinitialize?

Comment: Use previous version of camera plugin

Comment: Try to re intinalise the camara by using controlle on onResume()

Comment: You mean `model.cameraController.resumeVideoRecording();`?

Comment: yes On resuming, re inatinalise the camera

Comment: I assume On resume would work when there is an ongoing video recording, this happened during the camera preview

Comment: Check out this blog https://medium.com/@navinkumar0118/take-a-picture-using-flutter-camera-a9c11d282632

Comment: Great!
This fixes it, thanks @NavinKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On resume re initialise Camera

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _controller != null
        ? _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize()
        : null; //on pause camera is disposed, so we need to call again "issue is only for android"
  }
}
```

checkout https://medium.com/@navinkumar0118/take-a-picture-using-flutter-camera-a9c11d282632

Comment: Works now but after the activity resumed, I still had to tap on anywhere on the screen to get the camera working.